How do Turing machines compare to Lakoffian cognitivism?
It intrigues me that a Turing machine is a mathematical abstraction, arguably without a single universal or canonical formulation or definition. We can prove various systems are Turing-equivalent, but there is no “center” to this collection of things. On a deeper level, every Turing machine seems (and I am getting Platonist suddenly even though I never have been) like a valid structural manifestation, in our ontological world, of some sort of “pre-ontological” principles. By pre-ontological, I mean something utterly lacking in “existence in the world” - the world as we know it, that is. (Side note, perhaps this relates to Heidegger’s notion of “being in the world”?)
To be utterly clear, the rules by which humans modify certain drawings of ink on paper (“mathematics”), a Macintosh computer, the card game Magic the Gathering, certain ways of directing water flowing through tubes, and the human mind (it seems) are Turing-equivalent, but none of them counts as “the actual thing that the other things are an example of”.
It interests me that ontologically, we have no idea how many Turing machines remain to be discovered. We just have to discover that pattern in any subdomain of the world’s ontology. Not just in terms of physical substance (compositions of sounds, smells), but more importantly, in terms of a structural formulation in terms of some primitive notions. There are deeply conceptually different ways of arriving at a UTM. Some accept quantifiers as a primitive notion; others, for-loops; some assume the ability to add natural numbers, others, to follow a conditional rule on a set of strings. It was even discovered that a single binary person, NAND, can give rise to a complete Boolean algebra.
This has struck me as a very weird problem. Since there is no currently unified basis for all of mathematics, it is thoughts like these that make me interested in coherentism - that the logico-ontological structure of the world does not have any “beginning”, but a possibly infinite collection of equivalent beginnings, each of which can be used to derive the others. It would be cool if the ultimate proof in mathematics were some way of having axioms prove themselves, but oh darn, maybe that is exactly what Gödel’s incompleteness theorem is about.
Now, I think George Lakoff has a theory that attaches to a very, very different but philosophically ample view on these questions. The simple/“naive” idea is that human thought reduces to some fundamental/atomic “cognitive operations” which are extended to interpret the world, as “metaphors” (some way of structurally adapting those elemental cognitive abilities to higher-level, conceptually composite domains). The deeper aspect of the theory, which I don’t know anything about, is how this opens a different perspective for the ontology of mathematics itself (I think).
My question is, when we compare Lakoff’s suggested atoms of cognition to the abstract capabilities of a Turing machine, does it become obvious that Lakoffian cognition is just another Turing machine? Does Lakoff’s view have any deep philosophical defense, against being reduced to “a system running on a Turing machine”? And/or, could these Lakoffian atoms be abstracted into a formal system, such that we could actually use it axiomatically as a foundation for mathematics? (Saunders Mac Lane is known to have had similar ideas to Lakoff.)

"arguably without a single universal or canonical formulation or definition" This is false. There is a single canonical definition.

Turing computability is considered on of the more "stable" concept in modern mathematics: "there are many other models of computation that have the same computing power as Turing machines" that means that we have many mathematical (i.e. abstract) models of computation, all equivalent.

None of the things you call Turing equivalent (mathematics, computers, card game, human mind) are Turing equivalent.

"we have no idea how many Turing machines remain to be discovered."... this seems to me not relevant. The interesitong thing (connected to the above) is whether there will be further abstract model of computation.

The set of Turing machines is countable, so we do have an idea of how many are left to be discovered.

You really should stop posting extended lectures on topics you are not familiar with.

@DavidGudeman I think he might mean that we have no idea how many models of computation remain to be discovered, but that isn’t too interesting of a question. There’s at least countably infinitely many (we can modify the canonical formulation of TMs so that any right move on the tape moves by n cells, and it would still be equivalent to the canonical formulation)

There are too many problems with this question to address them all in the comments, so I'm going to do it in an answer. The question contains many misstatements and misunderstandings.

There is, in fact, a single canonical formulation of Turing machines, and has been since Alan Turing first wrote about them. Possibly what you mean is that there is no single canonical formulation of computability, but that isn't quite correct either. What exist are several different ways to view computation, and they turn out all to be equivalent in terms of the functions they can compute.

Mathematics is not Turing equivalent because it is not a computation method.

Physical computers are not Turing equivalent because they have finite state.

Card games are not Turing equivalent because they are not a computation method and have finite state.

The human mind is not Turing equivalent because it has finite state and can do lots of things that a Turing Machine can't do.

It is not true that we have no idea how many Turing machines remain to be discovered. In fact the set of Turing machines is countable so there are countable Turing machines yet to be specifically written down, but on the other hand, one can construct an algorithm for producing all possible Turing machines.

I doubt that "there are deeply conceptually different ways of arriving at a UTM." It's a pretty straightforward TM programming problem.

And the other hand, since you add "Some accept quantifiers as a primitive notion; others, for-loops; some assume the ability to add natural numbers, others, to follow a conditional rule on a set of strings" maybe you don't know that a UTM is a Turing machine and you mean that there are "deeply conceptually different" ways of defining computability. That would be a more proper claim but not uncontroversial.

There is no question that there are multiple equivalent ways of providing a foundation for mathematics.

A Turing machine is not a set of elements, but a structure for writing a set of rules. If there are a finite set of "atoms of cognition", this doesn't say anything about the rules under which those atoms are used, so if you see a connection to Turing machines, you need to spell out what you mean and explain how the existence of a finite set of atoms makes a difference.


